# Is there a shortcut or extension to automatically add image width and height to <source> images inside of <picture> element?

Tags: html, image, responsive-design

There is a quick way to adding width and height for images on  element using vscode shortcut 1. CMD + Shift + P  2.Emmet update image size. But this trick doesn't work on  inside of  element. Is there a shortcut or vscode extension to make that happen? I mostly work with  element so this would be big productivity boost.

I tried searching through vscode docs and there is no shortcut for picture element or browser extension to my knowledge.